# Percentage discount only on not in-sale items subtotal in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

[There is an excellent answer for discount based on not-in-sale items count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767754/cart-discount-based-on-cart-item-count-and-only-for-items-that-are-not-in-sale/49751947?noredirect=1#comment86518289_49751947) but If there is one item-in-sale in the list it's not working for all other not-in-sale items...

My question is: How can I make discount only to the "items not in sale" when I have "items in sale" in the same cart list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated** - Try this instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'custom_cart_discount', 20, 1);
function custom_cart_discount( $cart ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Limitations: Only when there is 5 or more non on sale items in cart
    $starting_limit = 5;

    // Initialising variables
    $not_on_sale_subtotal = $discount = $items_count = 0;

    // Iterating through each item in cart
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){

        // For cart items is not on sale
        if( ! $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
            $not_on_sale_subtotal += (float) $cart_item['line_subtotal'];
            $items_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }
    }

    // Discount calculation
    $discount = $not_on_sale_subtotal * 0.1;

    // Applied discount only cart items that are not on sale
    if( $discount && $items_count >= $starting_limit )
        $cart->add_fee( 'Special discount', -$discount );

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Should works

Comment: thank you but it is not working, the basket page is white, I am now checking (with my limited software ability) it