# Woocommerce discount on second item when not on sale items are in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

Now I have the following Woocommerce discount: 1) at one item --> 10% only for not in sale items 2) at two items 20% for the cheapest item including on sale items

I tried use [Cart discount based on cart item count and only for items that are not in sale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767754/cart-discount-based-on-cart-item-count-and-only-for-items-that-are-not-in-sale/41775343#41775343) 
and [Cart discount for product that cost less in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693564/cart-discount-for-product-that-cost-less-in-woocommerce/49698427#49698427) answers code.

How can I add 10% discount, when I have two items, to the second item?

How can add discount only for not in sale items when I have two items, to the second item?

Answer (score 1):

The following will make a 10% discount on the 2nd item when there is not items on sale in cart:

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees' , 'custom_2nd_item_discount', 10, 1);
function custom_2nd_item_discount( $cart ){

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Only for 2 items or more
    if ( $cart->get_cart_contents_count() < 2 )
        return;

    // Initialising variable
    $has_on_sale = false;
    $count_items = $discount = 0;
    $percentage  = 10; // 10 %

    // Iterating through each item in cart
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        $count_items++;
        if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_sale() ){
            $has_on_sale = true;
        }
        if( 2 == $count_items ){
            $discount = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $cart_item['data'] ) * $percentage / 100;
        }
    }

    // Apply discount to 2nd item for non on sale items in cart
    if( ! $has_on_sale && $discount > 0 )
        $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("2nd item %s%% Discount"), $percentage), -$discount );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.